How to rank gene list obtained from random effect moled of MetaVolcanoR Package using topconfect package
I'm conducting a meta-analysis on GSE datasets using the metavolcanoR package. For subsequent analyses, I require gene ranking. To ensure consistency in ranking genes perturbed across all studies, many studies have employed the Topconfects approach.I've studied several articles exploring the utilization of Topconfects for ranking gene lists derived from REM of MetaVolcanoR. However, the challenge lies in determining which column of the REM table should be utilized for ranking(randomSummary? randomCi.lb?randomCi.ub? or randomP?).
Here is a small part of the output table(metaRem) from the Random Effects Model.
MetaRem table
I used this code for ranking gene list(metaRem):
z <- c(1:nrow(metaRem))
pfunc <- function(i, effect_size) {
  pnorm(z[i], mean=effect_size, lower.tail=FALSE)
}
nest_confects=nest_confects(length(z), pfunc, fdr=0.05)
nest$table

and a small part of the output table is:
Obtained ranked gene list
what I expect is like the table below:
Expected Ranked gene list
